# Spring boot security 6 - swagger 3: CSRF token only worked second call

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-rest, swagger-3.0, spring-security-6

I'm implementing spring boot security in our Java 17 project which uses Swagger 3. The login procedure appears when navigating to the swagger-UI before we can call one the endpoints. Which is normal. The login is successful and I'm navigated to the API-endpoints overview. So far so good.

When I want to execute one of the endpoints, the login message appears again and spring security logs says 'invalid CSRF token'. When I cancel the login pop-up and refresh the page. The login pop-up appears again. After successful login I'm again redirected to the API-endpoints overview. If I execute one of the API-endpoints again the call is successful and so the CSRF-token is valid.

Has anyone an idea why this flow occurs?

The security configuration class looks like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                /*
                 * Support Javascript based applications (use json instead of HTML)
                 * Otherwise application throws 'Invalid CSRF token'
                 * https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1-SNAPSHOT/servlet/exploits/csrf.html
                */
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I enabled CSRF token in swagger 3 by setting the property below in application.yml

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    csrf:
      enabled: true
```

Kind regards

Successfully call API-endpoints via Swagger 3 at the first attempt after the login procedure.